# Removing \xa0 from dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, data-cleaning

I have a list of NBA team names that have doubled up. How do I remove the entries with \xa0?

This is the output I get.

```
['Atlanta Hawks', 'Atlanta Hawks\xa0', 'Boston Celtics', 'Boston Celtics\xa0', ect
```

I am removing the seed from the webscraping process by

```
teams["Team"] = teams["Team"].str.replace("(1)", "", regex=False)
teams["Team"] = teams["Team"].str.replace("(2)", "", regex=False)

teams["Team"] = teams["Team"].str.replace("(15)", "", regex=False)
```

How to I get my list to not include the \xa0 entries?

Comment: if your list is called `teams` then you can remove items from that list with a list comprehension like `[team for team in teams if "\xa0" not in team]`

Comment: You want to remove "\xa0" from entities or remove the entities that includes that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: include your full script here. It's likely we can fix this higher up your script